# How to detect a surge of activity in a video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to automatically detect a surge of activity in a video, e.g. basketball jump shot, hockey face-off, sprinters starting, etc., preferably using ffmpeg.

In these instances, there's some motion as the players assume their positions, followed by a pause as they wait for the ref to throw the ball or drop the puck, followed by a lot of motion as all players begin to react.  It's also typical that the camera will be still during this period and begin moving as the ball or puck changes position.

I've tried using the 'select' filter `select='gt(scene,0.4)'`, but that seems to be more concerned with scene changes (i.e., more dramatic changes) even with low thresholds.

I also tried exporting the scene information and examining it manually, but couldn't find a clear pattern that correlated with motion in the video.

UPDATE: I ran a `mestimate` on the video.  Processing took a long time, but there was definitely a change in activity before and at point of interest.  Is there a way to export this information to a file, or otherwise detect the amount of motion seen my `mestimate`?